# Pushing data into Mongoose Model array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i am trying to push string into an array in mongoose. But it is not updating.

My Model is

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
  project:{
    type: new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: [String], //tryxing to push data here
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
      }
    }),

  },
  isAdmin: Boolean
});
```

and in the code i am doing

```
router.put('/addProject', auth, async (req, res) => { //To update password
user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,{project:{$push :{name:req.body.projectname}},new :true});

        /*********OR********/
        User.findOneAndUpdate(
           { _id: req.user._id }, 
           {project:{ $push: { name: req.body.projectname  } }},
          function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(success);
                }
            });
```

i tried both the approaches but it is showing me empty array. And if there is already data in it get deleted everytime i run this route..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `project` and `name` fields to:

```
project:{
    name: [{
        type: String, // and not `type: [String]`
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
      }
    }]
},
```

The final schema would be:

```
// user.model.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
  project:{
    name: [{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
      }]
  },
  isAdmin: Boolean
});

export default User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then in your controller:

```
import User from './user.model';

router.put('/addProject', auth, async (req, res) => {
user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, 
  { $push: { 'project.name': req.body.projectname }, { new: true });
...
```

**Edit:** To remove an element from the array use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, 
  { $pull: { 'project.name': req.body.projectname }, { new: true });
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but still it is giving me empty array in response

Comment: I am printing the id and projectname in console.. i also tried the hard coded value of string ..but still it didnt worked

Comment: and it works without $push but replace the value which is already there..

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(req.body.projectname)` and `console.log(typeof req.body.projectname)` ?

Comment: first console shows the project name which is i am giving

Comment: and now if i want to delete something from the array? how can i do this?.. Thanks a lot for your help